# SWT - Shrink composite when one child is hidden

Tags: java, swt

I have a composite with GridLayout. On the first row there is just some text. On the second row there is a button. If i press the button i set the text on the first row to not visible, but everything stays in place. How can i "shrink" the composite so everything that is below the hidden text moves up to take its place?

Here is what i got so far:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());


        final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setText("Just some text");

        Button b1 = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
        b1.setText("Button1");
        b1.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
              switch (e.type) {
              case SWT.Selection:
                  label.setVisible(!label.getVisible());
                break;
              }
            }
          });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the label set the layout data:

```
GridData labelLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
label.setLayoutData(labelLayoutData);
```

When you change the visibility of the label also set the `GridData` `exclude` flag:

```
label.setVisible(!label.getVisible());

labelLayoutData.exclude = !label.isVisible();
```

Finally call `layout` of the `Composite`

```
composite.layout(true, true);
```